# ForkJoinPool thread spawning new threads

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

Let's say that I have to run some (mostly independent) expensive tasks in parallel. Normally this can easily be done using the fork/join framework.

My problem is that, some of those tasks may also spawn subtasks, using a different ForkJoinPool (in some method deeper down in the call hierarchy). I know that this will spawn many threads, which may slow down my application, and I would like to avoid that. One solution is to use the global pool and add tasks there, but this is not an option in my case.

The reason this is useful for me is that some of the original tasks are dependent and may wait for each other. For example, say A1 and A2 are two tasks which need the results of B (which is parallelizable) in order to proceed to C1 and C2 respectively. In that case, the threads running A1 and A2 can focus on B to improve CPU utilization. A simple example is shown below.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public int expensiveComputation(int x) {
    int result = x;
    // do stuff using different ForkJoinPool!
    return result;
}

public abstract class A {
    public abstract run(int x);
}

public class A1 extends A {

    public A1(int x) {
        super(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
        // Only 1 thread will run this for a given value of x
        map.putIfAbsent(x, expensiveComputation(x));
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class A2 extends A {

    public A2(int x) {
        super(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
        // Only 1 thread will run this for a given value of x
        map.putIfAbsent(x, expensiveComputation(x));
        // do stuff
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<A> tasks = new LinkedList<>();
    tasks.add(new A1(0));
    tasks.add(new A2(0));
    // More tasks

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
    pool.submit(() -> tasks.parallelStream().forEach((x -> {
        x.run();
    })));
}
```

Is it possible to utilize the "parent" pool from within those tasks? In the example above, the parent pool is the one in the main method. 
Naturally, I would like to do this without passing it as an argument through a long chain of method calls or using a global variable. Ideally I would like to restrict my program to the number of threads used by the parent pool, without doing any such tricks.

Comment: This is too much handwaving to produce a solid answer. Can't you explain your question in code?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I added some example to illustrate my problem. Let me know if I need to further clarify things.

Comment: The F/J framework is for Directed Acyclic Graphs. When you get into cyclic processing you're going to experience a world of hurt. Creating multiple FJPools will not solve your problem. You need a different product.

Comment: There aren't any cycles in my example. The thing is that both, A1 and A2, execute something that is common (B with x=0 in my example), and thus its result can be cached instead of computed twice. While A1 and A2 are waiting, I would like to utilize the waiting thread inside B to speed it up. However, if I blindly create new pools/threads then it may slow down my application, especially in case A1 and A2 do not happen to call B with different values for x.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph You are not going from earlier to later Tasks. You have dependencies between Tasks and F/J is the wrong product for that. You probably will need to design your own multi-threading structure.